# Do I need my Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty disk for Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

I understand that I need to own Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty to play Heart of the Swarm, but I'm not sure where my disk is. If I can't find it, do I need to buy WoL again before I can play HotS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you purchased this disc version of Heart of the Swarm, it contains everything you need to play, you [won't need to install Wings of Liberty first](https://us.battle.net/support/en/blog/9064004/).

If you purchased the digital version, downloading HotS will also get you everything you need for WoL.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need the disc, as you can download StarCraft 2: Wings of Liberty directly from the [Battle.Net](http://battle.net) website:

- Log in with your Battle.Net account
- Choose the Account link in the top right
- In the "Your Game Accounts" list, find StarCraft 2
- Click the Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty or StarCraft 2: Heart of the Swarm link to go to the Game Management Page
- From here you can download the Windows client. You can also select More Downloads to access the page with the Mac client download link.